# Kernel-level thread modify .text area?

Tags: linux, multithreading

I don't really understand the difference between the user-level threads and kernel-level threads. This is what i know so far:

**Kernel-level** threads

Advantages:

- if we have multiple processors/cores we can actually run the threads simultaneously ( true parallelism because the kernels scheduler has control over the threads )
- blocking a thread ( for I/O operations for example ) don't block all the threads

Disadvantages:

- context switch is made in kernel ( which means it's slower than in user-space )

**User-level** threads

Advantages:

- Faster context-switch
- Scheduling can be planned in the application ( not by OS scheduler )

Disadvantages:

- Kernel doen't know anything about the threads so at most the process will use one processor/core at a time.
- If one thread make a blocking call, all the threads will be be blocked again because the kernel has no knowledge about the existence of the threads, and the scheduler will give other process access to the processor/core, even though other threads in this program could run.

From what I know so far I can't answer to this **question**:

How does the .text(code area) of the process modifies when a kernel-level thread is created?

My intuition says that it won't change because the threads share the same address space, thus the .text area won't change. Another reason I find to support this answer is that the .text area is read-only. Moreover all the others areas will remain the same(.bss, heap etc). The only one that will change is the stack.

However I want to be sure that this is the correct answer.

Note: I mainly talk about the threads on linux kernel(don't know many stuff about windows threads)

Comment: By kernel threads are you talking ~processes?  And by user-threads are you talking ~pthread threads in user-space or "green" threads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 4 different types of threads that may be asked about here.

1. Threads created by the kernel itself to handle background tasks.
2. Processes forked by the `fork()` syscall.
3. pthread threads which are created by the user with the Linux `clone()` syscall but are managed by the kernel
4. "green" threads that run outside of the kernel scheduler entirely

The following answer assumes that "user-level" threads mentioned in the post are the pthread variety and *not* the "green" variety.

**Edit:** I think @Hristo is right and the OP is talking about "green" threads or is confusing the two.

This answer assumes you are talking about threads that you create with `pthread_create()`.  There are also ["green" threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads) which are are scheduled by user-space and are unknown to the kernel.  I'll leave my answer here for posterity.

---

**User Threads == green threads**

So called "green threads" are by definition threads that are handled entirely by the VM without kernel involvement.

> "User-level" Kernel doen't know anything about the threads so at most the process will use one processor/core at a time.

Right.

> If one thread make a blocking call, all the threads will be be blocked again because the kernel has no knowledge about the existence of the threads

No.  As long as you using the right primitives, a blocking call will cause the thread to be put in a wait queue and another green-thread to be run.

> How does the .text(code area) of the process modifies when a kernel-level thread is created?

In green-threads, they all use the same code area.

> Moreover all the others areas will remain the same(.bss, heap etc).

Yes.

---

**User Threads == pthreads**

With `pthread_create()` "user-threads", there is little difference between them and "kernel" threads.  The linux kernel implements user-level threads as a separate kernel processes using the `clone()` system call.  `clone()` creates a new process that uses the same memory space as the parent process as opposed to `fork()` which creates a new process with a *copy* of the parents memory.

> "User-level" Kernel doen't know anything about the threads so at most the process will use one processor/core at a time.

No, this is not correct.  The kernel manages the user-level threads just like any other process in that there is context switching and the ability to schedule the various user-level threads on multiple CPUs, etc.

> If one thread make a blocking call, all the threads will be be blocked again because the kernel has no knowledge about the existence of the threads

No, one threads can block and the other threads will continue to run.  Again, this is under pthread style threads.

> How does the .text(code area) of the process modifies when a kernel-level thread is created?

When a new thread is created, it inherits the memory segmentation tables of its parent.  The text/code pages (and other read-only pages) are marked as read-only and the two threads share the memory for the lifetime of the threads.  All read-write pages are also shared *until* a write is made to those sections by the new thread at which point the page is copied to another location (copy on write).

> Moreover all the others areas will remain the same(.bss, heap etc).

No, the heap pages, and anything else that is not marked as read-only (including the stack that you mention), will be copied as soon as they are written to.  I'm not sure about .bss sections but since they are initialized at runtime, I believe they are also read-write.  DATA is read-only.

Comment: On the last part I disagree. If you use fork() system call that means you create a process, not thread.

Comment: Good point @QtLearner.  I use the work "fork" liberally and did not mean the `fork()` system call.  I've edited my post and changed "fork" to "create".  Thanks.

Comment: But still it's wrong because you talk about what happens after fork(). Threads share same address space. That's why it's better to use them over processes(when it's possible of course), because the context switch is cheaper ( no TLB flush ), just register changes.

Comment: There is `fork()` and there is `clone()`.  `fork()` creates a whole new process with a separate memory space.  `clone()` creates a new process but with a shared memory table as I mention.  `pthread_create()` (and Java `new Thread()`) does a `clone()`.

Comment: Then what's the difference between kernel-level and user-level threads in linux? I'm really confused right now.

Comment: If you are talking about pthread threads then I'm saying that there is _very_ little difference.  Under linux, user-threads are implemented using kernel threads.

Comment: @Gray, I think QtLearner is talking about kernel managed threads (LWPs = lightweight processes) vs completely userspace managed threads (green threads, coroutines, etc.), not about threads in userspace vs different parts of the kernel running in parallel. POSIX threads are implemented as LWPs i.e. they are managed by the kernel and are created by `clone()`. Generators in Python are example of userspace threads - thread switch happens explicitly on the `yield` statement.

Comment: Maybe @Hristo. I specifically asked at the start if he was talking about pthread create or green threads.  Unfortunately "user-threads" is pretty ambiguous.  By now I'm not sure what he means.

Comment: The definition of user-level threads in the question matches the description of threading implemented completely in userspace (e.g. libpth).

Comment: In reading the `pth` manual @Hristo, you are correct.  He's obviously talking about green threads.  I'll tune my answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The text of the program changes when switching from user-level threads to kernel-level threads (also known as LWPs or *lightweight processes*). The reason for that is that the two kinds of threading are implemented/coded in completely different ways.

Kernel-level threads are just separate instruction flows that share everything except the stack and the thread-local storage (TLS). They are mostly treated like real processes by the kernel but they are lightweight in that they share lots of resources with each other. Actually single threaded processes in Linux are just processes that have only one LWP plus all the other kernel structures that makes it a full-blown process. LWPs execute concurrently more or less as usual separate Linux processes execute - you don't need to do anything to make them run concurrently - it's all done by the kernel scheduler. The difference with full-blown processes is that LWPs share most of their data. They also share the `.text` section of the executable but in reality the `.text` section is shared between all instances of the same executable, not only between its LWPs.

User-level threads provide something similar to the real multithreading but it is really a timesharing solution often driven by explicit switching mechanisms. It means that as one user-level thread is executing all other are put on hold since there is only one stream of instructions running that is jumping from one point in code to another together with save/restore of some CPU registers (most notably the stack pointer). One form of user-level threads is the cooperative multitasking implemented in `libpth` (GNU Portable Threads). User-level threads add special machinery to the user code that allows threads to run in what is perceived to be simultaneous mode. `libpth` for example requires that each thread calls specific API function to allow for some other thread to run. Timer signals can be used to preempt user-level threads but this is usually not possible if the process is currently stuck in a blocking syscall. That's why user-level threads are usually written using advanced stuff like asynchronous I/O, non-blocking operations and so on, completely different from the kernel-level threads where making blocking syscalls is perfectly acceptable. As far as the kernel is concerned this all happens in a single kernel-level thread.

The most notable example of something similar to user-level threads is using `select()` or `poll()` to process multiple network connections in parallel in a single-threaded executable. The "thread" state in this case is the connection state structure that is then used in calls to the specific communication function that processes data on the socket that was detected as active by the polling syscall.

Converting a user-level thread to a kernel-level one usually requires changes to the source code (e.g. calls to the switching API have to be removed) and therefore the `.text` section also changes. Converting a kernel-level thread to a user-level one also requires changes to the source code and might not be always possible. You cannot just plug the name of a function that implements a user-level thread in a call to `pthread_create()` although it *might* be possible if the user-level threading implementation uses something like timer signals and the thread does not call special switching APIs...

Another notable difference between the two threading implementations is that in the cooperative threading it is really hard to have a race condition or a sharing violation (i.e. two threads reading-modifying-writing the same memory location at once) simply because the control is transferred at well-known points in the code while in the preemptive case the process can be interrupted anywhere inbetween (e.g. one could say that in the cooperative case all operations are atomic) and such access has to be guarded by critical sections or by other synchronisation primitives.

Just for the sake of completeness, Windows also has its own implementation of user-level threads called *fibers*.

Answer (score 0):

User-level threads don't actually exist in Linux. Whenever you create a new thread with pthread_create a corresponding kernel level thread is also created. Using `strace` it should be clear that the `clone()` system call is called whenever you create a new thread.

In any case, all threads share .text, .data and .bss sections.
The only thing they do not share is their stack.  (Yes, yes, and thread local variables. Let's not get into that.)

Comment: User-level threads (i.e. "green" threads) do exist in Linux.  A number of different VMs support them.

Comment: Example of user-level threading library for Linux is `GNU pth` (GNU Portable Threads) which is really OS independent.